# Renderizado de api con next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

Estoy intentando usar la API de themoviedb con next js 13, realizó el fetch con promises, pero al

querer renderizar la response no se hace, ni me da ningun error al respecto, qué es lo que

estoy haciendo mal, o que me falta para poder renderizarlos en el html, dejo abajo el código,

gracias.

```
 const FetchPelis = async () => {
 const key = "------------------------";
 return fetch(
  `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=${key}&language=es`
 )
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => data.results);
 };

 async function Pelis() {
 const data = await FetchPelis();

 return (
   <>
   {data.map((post, index) => {
     <div key={index}>
       <h4>{post.name}</h4>
       <p className="data">{post.id}</p>
     </div>;
   })}
  </>
 );
}

export default Pelis;
```

y luego es llamado en el page de home '/'

```
 import Pelis from "./components/pelis";

 async function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <Pelis />
    </>
   );
 }
```

Salida `data`:

```
{
backdrop_path: '/mWGLIaVFXyalsSbstiwletjKFUC.jpg',
first_air_date: '2011-02-28',
genre_ids: [ 18, 80 ],
id: 31586,
name: 'La Reina del Sur',
origin_country: [ 'US' ],
original_language: 'es',
original_name: 'La Reina del Sur',
overview: 'string',
popularity:1019.568,
poster_path:'/uBTlJDdPpRxYTfUnKw4wbuIGSEK.jpg',
vote_average: 7.8,
vote_count: 1611 
}
```

Comment: comparte el `console.log(data)` del componente `Pelis`

Comment: el console me da todos los datos correctamente, es poreso que no entiendo el fallo al querer renderizar, probe tambien poniendo data?.map...

Comment: {backdrop_path: '/mWGLIaVFXyalsSbstiwletjKFUC.jpg',first_air_date: '2011-02-28',genre_ids: [ 18, 80 ],id: 31586,name: 'La Reina del Sur',origin_country: [ 'US' ],original_language: 'es',original_name: 'La Reina del Sur',overview: 'string',popularity: 1019.568,poster_path:'/uBTlJDdPpRxYTfUnKw4wbuIGSEK.jpg',vote_average: 7.8,vote_count: 1611
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que falta regresar el jsx del callback `data.map`, agrega el `return keyword`:

```
 <>
   {data.map((post, index) => {
     return <div key={index}>
       <h4>{post.name}</h4>
       <p className="data">{post.id}</p>
     </div>;
   })}
 </>
```

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias